# how to change {} to ${} in quarkus qute？

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-qute

how to change {} to ${} in quarkus qute?

there are some css,js in html.it error now.
for example:

```html
<style type="text/css">
            body\{background-color: #D0D9E0;\}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

$.ajax({
                    url: '/getUserinfo',
                    data: {accessToken: accessToken},
                    dataType: 'json', 
                    success: function(res) {
                        if(res.code == 200) {
                            layer.alert(JSON.stringify(res.data));
                        } else {
                            layer.alert(res.msg);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, type, errorThrown){
                        return layer.alert("异常：" + JSON.stringify(xhr));
                    }
                });
</script>
```

Comment: If you have a whitespace character around your `{` `}` characters, Qute should ignore them. So for example, instead of `body{...}` in your CSS, you can write `body { ... }` and it should be fine.

Comment: You can also try to use [unparsed character data](https://quarkus.io/guides/qute-reference#basic-building-blocks) block to mark the content that should be rendered but not parsed.